# Does AMD CrossFire work in windowed mode?

Tags: graphics-card, amd-radeon, crossfire

I've been considering picking up two of the new 6870s to run in CrossFire, as it seems like great performance for the price. Unfortunately, I've stumbled upon some people saying that CrossFire doesn't work in windowed mode. However, I'm having an incredible amount of difficulty finding out the truth about this, as though it is a closely guarded secret.

I'm just finding a couple of posts from 2006 and 2008 saying it doesn't work, and then a couple more saying it does work in DirectX 10 mode. Since I primarily play my games in windowed mode, this is very important and essential to me.

Can somebody please confirm to me whether or not CrossFire works in windowed mode? Does it require the games to be running in any particular DirectX version?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I finally found something on the [AMD knowledge base](http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/ATICrossFireXtechnologysupportforfullscreenDirect3DorOpenGLacceleratedapplications.aspx) about it:

> **Supported Applications:**
>
> ATI CrossFireX™ technology is only supported for full screen Direct3D or OpenGL accelerated applications on compatible ATI Radeon™ graphics accelerators. Windowed or cloned applications will only be accelerated by single GPU ATI Radeon™ graphics accelerators.

It looks like CrossFireX is fullscreen mode only, then. That's very disappointing.

Comment: makes sense though, since the rendering architecture has to split up drawing the entire screen -- that'd be a very strange process for windowed 3D with a GUI!